# Why do sequential containers have both size_type and difference_type?

Tags: c++, types, stl, containers

`vector<int>` has both `vector<int>::size_type` and `vector<int>::difference_type`. It seems unnecessary for both to exist since `size_type` is guaranteed to be able to hold a value as large as the maximum number of elements that a `vector<int>` may contain on a given system, and, in any valid use case, `difference_type` should necessarily be less than or equal to the maximum number of elements i.e. the distance between two elements in a sequential container will never be larger than the maximum number of elements that sequential container can contain. Could someone provide an example where there's a useful distinction between the two?

Comment: Having two different types for `size` and `difference` is regarded by some as mistake in the original design of STL. So don't put to much though on it. See for example. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvtFGa6XJDU

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`container::difference_type` exists because for some sequence containers you can subtract iterators.  That subtraction can result in a negative number.  You can't use `container::size_type` for that result as it is unsigned so you will never have a negative value.  So we  have `container::difference_type` which is a signed integer that is the `difference_type` of the iterator of the container.

Comment: What does it mean to "subtract iterators"? When is it a meaningful operation?

Comment: @Dai To find the distance between two elements in a container?